# Parsing a space delimited file and performing operations in bash

Tags: bash, delimiter

I am trying to read in a basic, space delimited file in bash and I want to perform operations on the variables.

What is the nomenclature for referencing certain "columns" in bash?
I am trying to explicitly use bash. If there is useful documentation that references specifically how to delimit files and perform basic operations- that would be very useful.

An example of the text document I have would be as follows:

```
123456789 LastName FirstName 1 2 3
123456789 LastName FirstName 1 2 3
123456789 LastName FirstName 1 2 3
123456789 LastName FirstName 1 2 3
123456789 LastName FirstName 1 2 3
```

I would like to sort it and perform operations on multiple columns.

I have done this using awk, but I would like to do this in bash. 
My awk implementation:

```
awk '{average = ($2 + $3 + $4)/3} {print (average, "["$1"]", $2",", $3); average = 0}' $'readme.txt'
```

How might this be achieved?

Comment: I have managed to implement this with awk- I am merely asking how to read the program in and how to reference variables outside of awk/sed.  I am not asking for the solution- just syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want [`sort`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) for sorting and splitting respectively.

`cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=LIST` where `LIST` is a comma separated list of column indexes returns the sections of each space-split line denoted by the indexes in `LIST`.

`sort --field-separator=' ' --keys=POS` sorts the lines of your file and outputs them to stdout. `--field-separator=' '` causes the positions to be delimited by spaces.

> POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field; both are origin 1. If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace. OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key. If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.

You can use [`expr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expr) and [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) for the math.

`wc -l` will give you the count of total lines.

If you have headers which need ignoring, use `tail -n +2` to get the whole file starting on the second line.

Strap everything together with pipes and subshells. In general the sort of processing you want is why `awk` has a place.

Comment: I gave a weird disjoint answer because I wasn't sure what the actual question was.